# How to prove importance sampling ratio is uncorrelated with action-value (or state-value) estimate?

Tags: proofs, off-policy-methods, sutton-barto, importance-sampling, model-free-methods

In Sutton & Barto (2nd edition), the following is mentioned [on page 150 (p. 172 of the pdf), section 7.4](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf#page=172):

> the importance sampling ratio has expected value one (Section 5.9) and is uncorrelated with the estimate.

How can we prove the importance sampling ratio is uncorrelated with the estimate?

Answer (score 1):

Sutton and Barto explain it themselves [in section 5.9](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf#page=136). I post it with a bit of context. **The equation you're looking for is 5.13**.[image: Excerpt from Section 5.9]